# Replace duplicates with NA after the maximum in a series has been reached

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

Imagine a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
id  t1  t2  t3  t4  t5
1   5   10  11  11  11
2   6   7   12  13  16
3   1   2   2   2   2
4   3   3   4   4   4
```

The numbers are consistently increasing across the rows, but at some point the number series reaches its maximum, and the same number is just repeated. How can I, using `R`, convert this into a `data.frame` where the "duplicated" numbers are replaced by a `NA` or simply left blank? I.e., into something like this:

```
id  t1  t2  t3  t4  t5
1   5   10  11  NA  NA
2   6   7   12  13  16
3   1   2   NA  NA   NA
4   3   3   4   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
dat[cbind(FALSE, t(apply(dat[,-1], 1, function(z) duplicated(z) & z >= max(z))))] <- NA
dat
#   id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5
# 1  1  5 10 11 NA NA
# 2  2  6  7 12 13 16
# 3  3  1  2 NA NA NA
# 4  4  3  3  4 NA NA
```

Breakdown:

1. Since we need to work row-wise, we'll use `apply(dat, 1, .)`.
2. On each row, we need those that are at-or-above the max value *and* duplicated, ergo the anon-func

   ```r
   function(z) duplicated(z) & z >= max(z)
   ```

   This by itself produces a transposed matrix (because of how R's `apply` operates), which we then `t`ranspose into a correctly-shaped logical matrix:

   ```r
   t(apply(dat[,-1], 1, function(z) duplicated(z) & z >= max(z)))
   #         t1    t2    t3    t4    t5
   # [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
   # [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
   # [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
   ```
3. We omitted the `id` column with `dat[,-1]`, but for reassigning `NA`, we need to `cbind(FALSE, .)` so that the `id` column is preserved.
4. Lastly, we reassign to just those fields by using `dat[.] <- NA`.

PS: the alternate functions used in other answers works just as well here:

```r
# equivalent with this sample data
function(z) duplicated(z) & z >= max(z)
function(z) seq_along(z) > which.max(z)
```

The largest differences in the answers (so far) is a preference towards R dialects, whether base or `dplyr+purrr`.

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(id = 1:4, t1 = c(5L, 6L, 1L, 3L), t2 = c(10L, 7L, 2L, 3L), t3 = c(11L, 12L, NA, 4L), t4 = c(NA, 13L, NA, NA), t5 = c(NA, 16L, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I thought of `df[cbind(FALSE, FALSE, (df[,-1] == apply(df[, -1], 1, max))[,-ncol(df)+1])] <- NA` but it's too similar to your answer to post it.

Answer (score 2):

One option using `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
df %>%
    mutate(pmap_dfr(across(-id), ~ `[<-`(c(...), seq_along(c(...)) > which.max(c(...)), NA)))

  id t1 t2 t3 t4 t5
1  1  5 10 11 NA NA
2  2  6  7 12 13 16
3  3  1  2 NA NA NA
4  4  3  3  4 NA NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @Martin Gal for suggesting such a clever hint. Yes we could indeed dispense with the `else` statement:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  pmap_df(~ {x <- c(...)[-1]
  ind <- which.max(x)
  if(ind < length(x)) {
    x[(ind + 1):length(x)] <- NA
  } 
  c(c(...)[1], x)
  })

# A tibble: 4 x 6
     id    t1    t2    t3    t4    t5
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     5    10    11    NA    NA
2     2     6     7    12    13    16
3     3     1     2    NA    NA    NA
4     4     3     3     4    NA    NA
```

Comment: It doesn't matter at all, but you can replace `x  } else {   x  }` simply with `} x`. You don't need an `else`-statement, just return `x` outside the `if`-construct.

Comment: Thank you dear Martin, could anyone be any nicer than you? :D My code also needed a small edit as I forgot to include `id` column in the output.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I could see was to melt the table to a long format (using the data.table melt function), and write a custom function that takes in a number series and returns the expected output. I then just cast the table back to the original format. I'm sure there are some nifty cool solutions out there that are far better, but at least this works as expected.

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table('id' = c(1,2,3,4),
                't1' = c(5,6,1,3),
                't2' = c(10, 7, 2, 3),
                't3' = c(11, 12, 2, 4),
                't4' = c(11, 13, 2, 4),
                't5' = c(11, 16, 2, 4))

x <- melt.data.table(x, id.vars = 'id')

find_max_replace_subsequent <- function(numbers){
  
  max_is <- max(numbers)
  max_found <- 0

  for(i in c(1:length(numbers))){
    current_number <- numbers[i]

    if(max_found == 1){
      numbers[i] <- NA

    }
    if(current_number == max_is & max_found == 0){
      max_found <- 1
    }
    
  }
  
  return(numbers)
}
x[, 'value' := find_max_replace_subsequent(numbers = value), by = c(by1 = 'id')]

x <- dcast.data.table(x, formula = id~variable, value.var = 'value')
x
```